# How to fill layout by including another layouts in code?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have layouts which will be repetitive added in main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/txt_temp_feels_like"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
    android:text="-"
    android:textColor="@color/gray"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

I want it to be added to this container:

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/temp_feels_like_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            </LinearLayout>
```

And I want to do it in code. I'm using this method:

```
private fun setData(
            layout: List<Int>,
            container: List<ViewGroup>,
    ) {
        for (i in layout.indices) {
            container[i].addView(layoutInflater.inflate(layout[i], null))
        }
    }
```

where layout is link to resource of layout.

And it's fill it but i have some problems:

1. I can't set text to this added view
2. I can't set weight to this view

Maybe my algorithm is wrong. Can you help?

Comment: How repetitive? Would a recycler view allow for simpler dynamic views to be added? If you add enough views then you'd need the linear layout to be scrollable and so the Recycler View would handle that for you.

Comment: @Chris 4 times.

Comment: If a recycler view is too much, then perhaps having the views in the layout file and just using visibility to control if they're visible or not may be another approach you could try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on when should you set the text and gravity. If you can set it before adding to layout - you can do something like that:

```kotlin
val view = layoutInflater.inflate(layout[i], null) as TextView
view.apply {
    text = "abc"
    params = (params as LinearLayout.LayoutParams).apply {
        weight = *value you need*
    }
}
container[i].addView(view)
```

Or if you need to set text to view after views are added to layout, you can reference to view via `container.children`/`container.getChildAt(i)`

**UPD**

you can get the child in the following way:

```
val count = layout.getChildCount()
var v: TextView? = null
for (i in 0..count) {
    val view = layout.getChildAt(i)
    if (view is TextView) {
        v = view
    }
}
```

Or one more way - set tag to view while adding it to layout and then you can get it by tag in any time you need

Comment: I have error "LinearLayout cannot be cast as TextView"

Comment: I forgot. I have layouts with LinearLayout not only with TextView

Comment: So how can i use TextView by "children" reference?

Answer (score 0):

Could something like this help?

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/temp_feels_like_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_temp_feels_like1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:text="-"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_temp_feels_like2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:text="-"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_temp_feels_like3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:text="-"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_temp_feels_like4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:text="-"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

You can have the gravity set appropriately (and the text if it's not dynamic),
and then set the visibility in code rather than try to add the view.

```
findViewById<View>(R.id.txt_temp_feels_like1).visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

Comment: unfortunately not :(